# ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I Am Working On SQL And I Am Facing A Problem In Creating The Table!
Here Is My Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Voucher_Types
(
    ID Number(3, 0),
    Abbreviation VarChar(2),
    Voucher_Type VarChar(100),
    EntryBy VarChar(25),
    EntryDate Date,
    CONSTRAINT ID_PK Primary Key(ID)
);
```

And I Get The Following Error,
**ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint**
I Am Using Oracle10g
I Goggled It And Found Some Topics But They Didn't Help Me, Can Somebody Help Me In This Problem! Thanks In Advance..!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have another table that has already a constrained with the name `ID_PK`.

If you want to find out which table it is, you might try

```
select owner, table_name from dba_constraints where constraint_name = 'ID_PK';
```

Most probably, you copied your `create table` statement but did not change the primary key's constraint name.

It is generally felt to be good practice to include the table name in a constraint's name. One reason is exactly to prevent such "errors".

So, in your case, you might use

```
CREATE TABLE Voucher_Types
(
   ... 
   CONSTRAINT Voucher_Types_PK Primary Key(ID)
);
```

**Update** Why can't the same constraint name be used twice? *(As per your question in the comment)*: This is exactly because it is a name that *identifies* the constraint. If you have a violation of a constraint in a running system, you want to know which constraint it was, so you need a name. But if this name can refer multiple constraints, the name is of no particular use.

Comment: Thanks To All For The Answering! I Understand The Problem But I Have One Question:
Why No Two Tables Have The Same Constraint Name Even Though They Have No Relation With Each Other..!!

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you that there's already another constraint named ID_PK in your schema - just use another name, and you should be fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Voucher_Types
(
    ID Number(3, 0),
    Abbreviation VarChar(2),
    Voucher_Type VarChar(100),
    EntryBy VarChar(25),
    EntryDate Date,
    CONSTRAINT VOUCHER_TYPES_ID_PK Primary Key(ID)
);
```

To find the offending constraint:

```
SELECT * FROM user_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'ID_PK'
```

Answer (score 1):

this means that there is a constraint named ID_PK try with 
`CONSTRAINT Voucher_Types_ID_PK Primary Key(ID)` for instance

you can check whether exists with

```
select * from user_constraints where upper(constraint_name) = 'ID_PK';
```

or

```
select * from all_constraints where upper(constraint_name) = 'ID_PK';
```

Answer (score 1):

you have same constraint name in other table
you need to change the constraint name

if you want to see table name which you used this constraint
you can see following query:

select table_name,constraint_name from user_constraints where lower(constraint_name)='id_pk';

Answer (score 0):

The anwser of Frank Schmitt is good.
However for the name of your constraint you can also use the table alias as part of your constraint name.
The name of your constraint would be something like: vte_pk. And there is no necessary to invoke the name of the concerning column in the constraint name.
What if the primary key is over 2 (or more) columns?

Thus `... CONSTRAINT VTE_PK Primary Key(ID) ...`.